# pyautogui: press two keys at the same time

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am using `pyautogui` to simulate pressing shift and end at the same time - when I type this myself, it highlights all the entries, however when I do it via the code below, it just moves to the end file - not highlighting every component, so it seems like shift isn't being pressed. Was wondering if anyone had any ideas?

```
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.keyDown('end')
pyautogui.keyUp('end')
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

Comment: Did you tried the hotkey function? It does the same rather than writing four lines just write pyautogui.hotkey('shif','end') presses the keys in linear order and releases them in reverse.

Answer (score 19):

I know this question is old, but you can get the same result by doing:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('shift', 'end')
```

Comment: Can you do this with three keys just with a diff parameter?